# Resample Raster File in Qgis

Tags: qgis

I have an Arc/Info image and I want to resample it in QGIS but I don't know how.. Anyone could help? I have already tried raster-> reprojection -> warp but it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @elena! Could you please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/189049/edit) your question to include details on how it didn't work? Did you receive an error message? Or did it crash? There are other resampling tools available from the _Processing Toolbox_ which you could try.

Comment: I believe that it didn't work because it changed the coordinates from the image..something that shouldn't happened.. thank you for you answer.. I'm going to try it

Comment: What do you mean by resample? Warp only changes the reference system. If you want to do what I think you want to do is to interpolate the image. Raster->Analyse->(Grid) Interpolate.

Comment: This can help calrify: Warp, resample and reclass are three different methods to achieve different results. Read more about [r.reclass](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.reclass.html), [r.resample](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.resample.html) and [r.proj](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.proj.html) to understand what they are.

Answer (score -2):

You can use GRASS tools.

**GRASS: r.reclass**
In the "Processing" toolbox, plugin >> GRASS GIS 7 >> Raster >> r.reclass

You can change the cellsize to a new value.